# Possible to show andengine scene in dialog instead of activity

Tags: android, andengine

currently i am evaluating posibilities of using andengine for my application (prototype used at presentation).

Is it possible, to show andengine scene in dialog, instead of activity?

What i mean, is i click button im my android activity, dialog pops up, and there is simple andengine scene in dialog...

Thanx for your help

Comment: you can create a dialog activity

Comment: ok i tested it and it seems a way to go... there still are some things to take care of for this to work but it works... post this as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok posting as an answer but I think this is already mentioned a couple of times. If you had to do any modifications and/or fixes add them to this answer

---

***Answer:***
Try to create the Activity with the dialog theme

One way to do this:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```